# Vim: Use "if" in augroup?

Tags: if-statement, vim, autocommand

I just want to define an autocommand that executes some external commands. For example, delete some auto-generated files after compilation. I work on both Windows and Linux, and the external commands used are different on these two platforms.

Therefore, I can define:

```
    if has("win32")
        autocmd foo bar_win
    else
        autocmd foo bar_nix
    endif
```

If I want to define this autocommand within a `augroup`, should I simply put this piece of code into an augroup like:

```
    augroup fooo
        autocmd!
        if has("win32")
            autocmd foo bar_win
        else
            autocmd foo bar_nix
        endif
    augroup END
```

I tried this method, and it seems this works. I am wondering if this is the correct way to do it. Another way I can think about is to write the external commands into a function within which I can use `if` statement. Then define autocommand in the usual way and call this function. Which is better?

Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely, both way work.  The first one is cleaner though, and marginally more efficient.

Comment: looks okay to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`augroup foo` and `augroup END` don't delimit a code block so it doesn't matter if you put your feature check there or elsewhere.

But you could follow this alternative pattern if you want safety *and* flexibility.

1. Define an empty autocommand group somewhere near the top of your `vimrc`:

   ```
   augroup foo
       autocmd!
   augroup END
   ```
2. Run your feature check later:

   ```
   if has("win32")
       autocmd foo Event * command for windows
   else
       autocmd foo Event * command for unices
   endif
   ```

   Since your autocommands belong to group `foo` they are correctly removed when you `:source $MYVIMRC`.